# String to integer conversion in PHP changes the value

Tags: php, string, integer, type-conversion

So I have this simple code:

```
$var = abs(crc32('string - 8 characters')).rand(100,999);
var_dump($var);
echo '<br>';
var_dump((int)$var);
echo '<br>';
var_dump(intval($var));
```

And the result:

```
string(13) "2047654753402"
int(2147483647)
int(2147483647)
```

Why the integer value is `2147483647`? I expected it to be `2047654753402`. I just want to convert the string to integer without changing the value.

Comment: Considering that your integer is a signed 32-bit integer..... what do you expect to happen when your string value is outside of that range? There's even a whole page of the PHP Documents that explains what happens when you have an integer overflow - http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Comment: If you need to work with integers that size, switch to 64-bit PHP

Comment: `Why the integer value is 2147483647?` Because `2147483647` is the maximum value that can be stored in a 32-bit signed integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not convert large string number to integer because interger has limitation -2147483647 to 2147483647. So If you want to convert number string to integer which has out of range of integer length, you can use double.

```
$var = abs(crc32('string - 8 characters')).rand(100,999);
var_dump($var);
echo '<br>';
var_dump((double)$var)
```

Comment: If you're recommending this as a solution, it might be worth noting that it will likely result in some loss of precision

Comment: What's wrong with this solution? I just want to be able to put this long number into database in BIGINT column.
This `(double)` returns a `float` number. Will it be correct to put it into BIGINT?

Comment: `What's wrong with this solution?` What's wrong is potential lack of precision..... try running `$var = abs(crc32('string - 8 characters')).rand(100,999);
var_dump($var);
$var2 = (double)$var;
var_dump($var2);
$var3 = (string)$var2;
var_dump($var3);` and see if `$var3` is the same as `$var`

Comment: Well, I've checked on 3 different servers and `$var3` returns exactly the same result as `$var`.

Comment: @Qrzysio - That's not guaranteed when the value is larger than PHP_INT_MAX.... it can also be affected by the precision setting in your php.ini file